# How to declare uint8 in for-loop initialization, as var is not allowed in for loop initialization

Tags: go

I am writing following code to calculate Population Count as below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var pc [256]byte

    for i := range pc {
        pc[i] = pc[i/2] + byte(i&1)
    }

    var x uint64 = 65535
    var population uint8

    for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {
        population  = population + pc[byte(x>>(i*8))]
    }

    fmt.Printf("Population Count: %d", population)
}
```

On compilation I get following error:

> prog.go:19:39: invalid operation: x >> (i * 8) (shift count type int,
>   must be unsigned integer)

The problem is with the variable `i` which is declared while initializing the for loop. The shorthand initialization of `i` makes it of type `int` which in internally of type `signed int32`. This is why the following line:

```
population  = population + pc[byte(x>>(i*8))]
```

is causing the problem. Because shift operator `>>` is expecting only unsigned integer, but the expression `i*8` results into `int` which is internally `signed int32`.

As `var` can not be used in `for` initialization.

```
for var i uint8 = 0; i < 8; i++ { ... }
```

> syntax error: var declaration not allowed in for initializer

I can declare variable `i` outside of `for loop`, but I do not find it clean and readable.

What should be the clean way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations)
>
> [Variable declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations)
>
> ... each variable is given the type of the corresponding
>   initialization value in the assignment.

---

`i := uint(0)`. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var pc [256]byte

    for i := range pc {
        pc[i] = pc[i/2] + byte(i&1)
    }

    var x uint64 = 65535
    var population uint8

    for i := uint(0); i < 8; i++ {
        population = population + pc[byte(x>>(i*8))]
    }

    fmt.Printf("Population Count: %d", population)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/H_4cn9w_dOq

Output:

```
Population Count: 16
```

Comment: Thanks peterSO for the solution. Its really clean one.

Comment: @AbhayKumar if you feel this answer solves your problem, kindly please approve it. for more information please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)